# `<td>` will be calculated if the display of the `tr` is not none

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

In my `cshtml` file, I want the `<td>` to be calculated if the display of the `tr` is not none.

```
<tr id="abc" style="display:none;height: 30px;">
<td class="titleStyle">Page:</td>

<td align="left">@Html.DropDownList(("pages"), 
(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["mypages"], new { onchange = "func()",
id = "page2",  style = "float:left; width: 276px;height: 20px;" })</td>
```

so I tried something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if ($("#abc").css("display") != "none") {

   }
</script>
```

but how can I continue from here?

any help appreciated!

Comment: What do you want to calculate? Your question is not quite clear. You want to get a reference to the inner `<td>` element?

Comment: ViewData["mypages"] is not defined. it will be defined when the display of the tr will not be none.

Comment: But what exactly are you trying to achieve? `ViewData["mypages"]` is a server side value, what's the relation with the javascript code you have shown? What do you want to calculate on the client? On the client you have a `<tr>` element with a `<td>` inside it and a `<select>` dropdown.

Comment: I have 2 buttons: papers and pages. I have some calculations that I do when the user press 'pages' (and insert them to the viewdata["mypages"]. when he presses 'pages' I change the display of the 'tr' to be inline. so I don't want the page will try to show this viewdata till the user doesn't press the pages. I hope you understand me..

Comment: Sorry but I really don't understand anything from your description. Hopefully someone else will be able to understand it and answer your question.

Comment: Maybe if you provided a full code example illustrating your scenario it would have made your question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this? Using [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) (IE9+)

HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="abc" style="display:none;height: 30px;">
            <td class="titleStyle">Page:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="abcd" style="height: 30px;">
            <td class="titleStyle">Page:</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName("tr"),
    length = trs.length,
    i = 0;

while (i < length) {
    if (window.getComputedStyle(trs[i]).display !== "none") {
        trs[i].children[0].firstChild.nodeValue = "Page: 1";
    }

    i += 1;
}
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/dLf8y/)